Need solution for being able to pick both images and videos on the same screen in react native
Need solution for being able to pick both images and videos on the same screen and send them to application at the same time in react native for both andriod and ios. I know that if you set media type to mixed in RN image picker it works only for ios. What is the solution for android. Can you share with me the communities solution.
would i need to use a native kotlin component with react native? Or is there a custom RN solution already built in RN somewhere in the community? Thanks

To allow users to pick both images and videos on the same screen in a React Native app, you can use a library like react-native-image-picker along with react-native-video. Here's a general outline of how you can implement this:
Install Dependencies:
First, install the necessary dependencies using npm or yarn:
npm install react-native-image-picker react-native-video
or
yarn add react-native-image-picker react-native-video
npm install react-native-image-picker react-native-video
or
yarn add react-native-image-picker react-native-video

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I believe you’ve misread the question.
